# Error using smartdiagram package:

Tags: tikz-pgf, errors, smartdiagram

I am trying to use the `smartdiagram` package and wanted to replicate an example in the documentation. Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\smartdiagram[circular diagram]{Set up,Run,Analyse,Modify~/ Add}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

When I compile it using `pdflatex`, I get this error:

> ! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
>   \pgf@selectfontorig ->\pgf@selectfontorig 
>                                             \nullfont  l.6 ...r diagram]{Set up,Run,Analyse,Modify~/ Add}
>                                                      !  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!

The same error crops up when compiling with `xelatex` and `lualatex`.

I am using an up to date TeXLive 2013 on an AMD 64 PC running Kubuntu 12.04.

Can someone please tell me what to do to get the example working?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `\smartdiagram` command creates its own `tikzpicture` environment, so there is no need to add that environment manually. In fact, the manual uses just a `center` environment, so a working example is

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\smartdiagram[circular diagram]{Set up,Run,Analyse,Modify~/ Add}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```